# PHP Cache issue when posting data using fsockopen

Tags: php, caching, mailchimp, fsockopen

I am using Mailchimp api 1.3 php wrapper. The problem is that a server where my customer hosts a site will cache response, it won't even make api call. The exact the same code works with me and other customers:

```
$api = new MCAPI($apiKey);
$doubleOptin = false;          
$mergeVar = array(
 'FNAME' => '',
 'LNAME' => ''
);                     
$api->listSubscribe($listId, $email, $mergeVar, 'html', $doubleOptin);  
print_r($api);
```

method listSubscribe() calls method callServer where I guess is the problem:

```
    $payload = "POST " . $this->apiUrl["path"] . "?" . $this->apiUrl["query"] . "&method=" . $method . " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $payload .= "Host: " . $host . "\r\n";
    $payload .= "User-Agent: MCAPI/" . $this->version ."\r\n";
    $payload .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $payload .= "Content-length: " . strlen($post_vars) . "\r\n";
    $payload .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n";
    $payload .= $post_vars;

    ob_start();
    if ($this->secure){
        $sock = fsockopen("ssl://".$host, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    } else {
        $sock = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    }    
    if(!$sock) {
        $this->errorMessage = "Could not connect (ERR $errno: $errstr)";
        $this->errorCode = "-99";
        ob_end_clean();
        return false;
    }

    $response = "";
    fwrite($sock, $payload);
    stream_set_timeout($sock, $this->timeout);
    $info = stream_get_meta_data($sock);
    while ((!feof($sock)) && (!$info["timed_out"])) {
        $response .= fread($sock, $this->chunkSize); 
        $info = stream_get_meta_data($sock);
    }
    var_dump($response); exit;
```

Does anybody have any idea why fsockopen and fwrite never sends call to Mailchimp? Weird thing is that I can actually read $response, but it is always the same from cache.

Comment: This sounds like something to take up with your hosting provider. Caching POST responses is really, really bad.

Answer (score 0):

If the code works for you and there is some query caching then you could try to add a timestamp to the request.

```
    "&time=".time()
```

This way you always have a "fresh" request.

Comment: I added that before and it didn't solve the problem, probably because it is POST and not GET, thus the url stays the same.

Comment: Put the `time` in the URL, even with POST.